# Click doesn't work in Windows Universal app with this code

Tags: user-interface, button, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I working on my project and I found this problem.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <Button
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Content="click"
         Width="110"
         Height="110"/>
</Grid>
```

paste this code on your project and run with one of Mobile Emulator 4" or 6" and wait to load complete, now rotate right or left your phone and try to click on the button on the screen and you can see it doesn't work.
when your remove

```
  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
```

it's work great. I found this problem when I try to create my own user control and i found this events **PointerPressed**, **PointerReleased**, **PointerExited** have problem when you use the **HorizontalAlignment** or **VerticalAlignment**, please if have windows 10 on your mobile phone try use this code and found what is problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the "touch" mode of the emulator, and isn't specific to your app. For example, if you try and use the Start Menu in landscape mode, you will find that it is similarly broken.

For now, you need to use the "mouse" mode instead (the arrow icon in the vertical toolbar next to the emulator).

Comment: Yeah i test the older version of windows 10 and it's work great but the latest version of mobile emulator have this problem, thanks for your answer and help, so how can i use the mouse mode? Is there any option for use mouse mode?!